# How to connect between microHDMI output to a DVI-I dual link input?

Tags: hdmi, dvi

I have a laptop with a microHDMI port, a mircoHDMI-HDMI cable and a monitor which has a DVI-I dual link input port.

I bought a female HDMI-male DVI-D dual link adaptor (just realised is it dual link).

I thought HDMI output is just digital so a DVI-D would suffice.  It didn't work cos my monitor detected no input signal.  Should it theoretically work or I have to get a female HDMI-male DVI-I duall link adaptor?

Comment: are you certain you were sending a video signal?

Comment: yes, cos i could see the monitor was trying to show up but it couldn't.  usually when one end of the cable is not connected to any video signal, you will get a "no video signal" displayed on the screen.

Comment: i just tried connecting from my microHDMI to HDMI cable => HDMI in to DVI-D dual link adaptor => DVI-D port monitor and it worked.  so i just wanna be sure if anyone had the same problem before i spend any more money and get a "Dual Link DVI-I adaptor".